# An antonym for "daylight"

Tags: antonyms

Considering that:

- The antonym of *day* is *night*.
- The antonym of *light* can be either *darkness* or *obscurity*.

Is there any exact antonym for *daylight*, a word that would mean "*the darkness of the night*", the same way *daylight* means "*the light of day*"?

I would use *darkness* in a conversation, but *darkness* is not necessarily associated with the *night* : it could be used to describe a dark room even when it's sunny outside. However, *daylight* cannot be used to describe a room lightened by a light bulb when it's dark outside.

*Edit :* I do not specifically look for a word recognised by a dictionary. A neologism used by a published author, and a culture reference would also be interesting.

*Edit 2 :* From tchrist's answer, it is now clear that no single-word expression exists for the concept I'm talking about (which is why I accepted the answer). However, *moonshine*, *moonlight* cannot match correctly since they define *light*, when the question is about defining *night darkness*. This reminds me of something Einstein once supposedly said to a teacher :

> There is no such thing as darkness. Darkness is nothing but the absence of light.

From this, while it is possible to *stand in the daylight*, one couldn't *stand in night darkness*, since darkness is nothing to be standing in. Similarly, while you can be *in water*, you can't actually be *in dryness*.

Comment: Night-time perhaps...

Comment: @mplungjan *Nighttime* would match *daytime*, that is, a period of time considered as "the night". It is more related to *time* than to *light* or *darkness* to me...

Comment: Night's dark may be more specific...

Comment: Who says there even has to be an antonym!?

Comment: @curiousdannii The guy with the accepted answer doesn't.

Comment: @curiousdannii a hard-line dualist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** — You aren’t likely to find something perfectly suitable through your approach to creating a compound word with both parts flipped.  Folks normally use either *in the dark* or else *by dark* or *by night* to oppose *in/by daylight*. However, you might try ***moonshine***.

### Dictionary Sources

The OED gives several examples of ***nightblack*** used to mean as dark as night, including these two:

> - 1817 Shelley *Rev. Islam* i. lii, ― On nightblack columns poised.
> - 1872 Tennyson *Gareth & Lynette* 1346 ― High on a nightblack horse, in nightblack arms.

It also attests the existence of ***night-dark***, as in this citation:

> - 1879 E. Arnold *Lt. Asia* 39 ― The night-dark steed.

### What’s an Antonym?

I don’t think you will ever get a one-word opposite of *daylight* that fits perfectly in all places where *daylight* is used.  *Daylight* a very old word dating from the thirteenth century which has come to be used in numerous ways:

- as a **noun** with any of several completely different meanings:

  - the light of day
  - the period between dawn and dusk
  - the moment when the sun first clears the horizon, so *dawn, daybreak, sunrise*
  - public awareness
  - the space between two things
- as an **attributive noun** like *daylight hours*
- as an **adjective** like in *daylighted buildings* or *daylighting techniques*
- in opposition to the **adjective** *standard* in time zone names like *Mountain Daylight Time* opposed to *Mountain Standard Time*
- as a **verb** (both transitive and intransitive) for bringing something to the surface, like a buried creek or building
- in **idiomatic expressions** like *to burn daylight* and  *the living daylights*

The top twenty collocations from COCA that immediately precede *daylight* are in order of occurrence
*broad, during, before, eastern, into, see, until, full, bright,
still, local, saw, natural, pacific, enough, fading, central, seen,
open,* and *ambient*.

The top twenty collocations from COCA that immediately follow *daylight* are in order of occurrence
*hours, time, saving, savings, left, between, basement, came, film,
outside, raids, streams, faded, comes, fades, bombing, attack, raid,
revealed,* and *pours*.

Your antonym presumably has to work in most of those places, and I don’t think you are going to come up with one.  You appear to believe that one can derive a reversible antonym of a compound word by inverting each of its pieces and putting them back together again.  That is not going to work in the general case, and it does not in general work here in this specific one either.  These are almost none of them sensible:

- weekend: daystart
- today: fromnight
- tomorrow: yestereve
- everyday: nonight
- moonlight: sundark, stardark
- sunup: moondown, shadedown
- latterday: formerdark
- yuleday: lithenight
- day watchman: night listenwomen
- sunrise: moonset, shadefall, nightfall
- daylaborer: nightleisurer
- lifetime: deathspace
- daywork: nightplay
- firework: waterplay

As you see, most of those just don’t work at all. Sometimes you even find yourself back to the same place you started due to “double negation”, such as when you oppose *sunup* with *shadedown* — which would mean the same thing.

### Published Examples

I’m not very fond of question that ask for neologisms, since that becomes nothing but a list question.  However, because you limited it to actual published words, there is some small hope of rescuing your question.

Now, you have chosen to limit the sense of *daylight* to the first one I listed above, which also happens to be its oldest use: the light of day, the day’s light.  That’s unfortunate because the only reasonable opposite for *light of day* is *dark of night*.

However, you do often find ***moonshine*** used as an opponent to *daylight*.  For example:

> He found he could **hide from daylight and moonshine**, and make his way swiftly and softly by dead of night with his pale cold eyes, and catch small frightened or unwary things.
>
> ―*The Lord of the Rings*, by JRR Tolkien

On the other hand, you have ***by night*** opposing ***by daylight*** here:

> Though I could forget it **by daylight**, forcing it, so to speak, away from my consciousness with worries about the presence or absence of soldiers, and the thousand lovely images of peak and cataract and swooping valley that assailed my eyes on every side, it returned **by night**, when, huddled in my blanket and cloak and burning with fever, I believed I heard the soft padding of its feet, the scraping of its claws.
>
> ―*Sword of the Lictor*, by Gene Wolfe

Neither of those are new words; they’re just what people use, and so probably what you should use as well.

If you had elected the “sunrise” sense instead, there actually are neologisms coined by published authors for what the opposite of that would be.  For example, Gene Wolfe uses ***shadelow*** and ***shadeup*** in his *Book of the Short Sun* and *Book of the Long Sun* portions of his Solar Cycle.

> From **shadeup** to
>   **shadelow**, the sun had been a torrent of white fire across a dazzling
>   sky; the wind, fair and strong at morning, had veered and died away
>   to a breeze, to an occasional puff, and by the time the market
>   closed, to nothing.
>
> ―*Caldé of the Long Sun*, by Gene Wolfe
>
> “You think I couldn’t? You think it because I’ve always been gentle with you for
>   your mother’s sake. It wasn’t like that in my family, believe me. Or in hers either. If you find yourself begging me before **shadelow** tomorrow,” to emphasize my point, I struck the table with the handle of the knife, “will you admit you were wrong? Are you man enough for that?”
>
> ―*On Blue’s Waters*, by Gene Wolfe
>
> A round gold sun that walks across the  sky during the course of the day, and vanishes into the sea at **shadelow**.
>
> ―*Return to the Whorl*, by Gene Wolfe

It’s too bad you have chosen the “light of day” sense of *daylight*, because Wolfe’s coinings are appealing for describing the dark and shady period between shadelow and shadeup.

Comment: While *nighttime* is related to time, *nightblack* seems to be more related to colour. I actually never heard that one though, and I quite like it... Thing is, I could not reverse the "antonym process" and get back to *daylight*...

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Well, if you don’t want a temporal answer and you don’t want a chromatic answer, what is it that you are looking for? This whole “antonym process” notion does not strike me as sound.

Comment: *Daylight* does not refer to either time, or colour. It might refer to *brightness* or simply *the presence of sunlight*. That's where I find a little (insignificant?) difference. I can't match "light" with "colour", but I'll admit the two notions are very close indeed.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith  Surely *dark* and *light* are opposites, and *black* is used as a stand-in for *dark*.  It’s not as though black, grey, and white are different hues.

Comment: I did not see it see way indeed... Yet, while I could say "*in the daylight*", "*in the nightblack/night-dark*" does not sound correct, as it would rather be expected as an adjective. *Daylight* can be used as a noun, and that's something I'm looking for... I am sorry if my question's not clear though.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith That’s the best I can do. I almost feel like I’ve been sent snipe-hunting.

Comment: Well I couldn't seriously not-accept such an answer for sure. I really appreciate the effort, and as a matter of fact, I do like *moonshine*, which involves associating the "night darkness" with the "moon light". I thought history would have coined the term I'm looking for, but since everything mentioned earlier matches... it may have never been needed. Thank you again!

Comment: In the Tolkien example, The subject (Gollum) is hiding from lights by day - daylight (the sun) and moonshite (the moon).  These are complimentary pairs and not opposing pairs, or antonyms.

Comment: @Oldcat I think you should edit your *shite* (!!!) to *shine*, and your *complimentary* to *complementary*. :)

Comment: @Oldcat: actually, *moonshine* could be associated to *moonlight*, which could not fit to define *darkness*. However, this answer clearly explains why my antonym can't be found, and provides more than satisfying alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

How about maybe: night darkness ?  nightfall ? dimness ?

Comment: *Night darkness* is a nice composition, and that's what I'd go for if no single-word expression matched. On the other hand, *nightfall* describes to process of switching between *daylight* and *night darkness* (or *word-I-am-looking-for*).

Comment: Well, after all (correct me if wrong), daylight seems to be composed by "day" used as an adjective + light. Night darkness would be almost parallel, except that, perhaps, being "darkness" itself a bit long, it seems strange to make a "unique" word.

Comment: I have found no such word in usual dictionaries, but I just asked this question out of pure curiosity. Maybe some writer created/used a term that wasn't actually *recognised*, but as a *neologism*. Or maybe is there a culture-related or religion-related word that could match.

Answer (score 0):

**Dark of night**. It's a bit more poetic than daylight, but it's at least an established phrase, unlike "night darkness" or similar. Furthermore, it can refer both to the darkness that comes at nighttime, as well as figuratively refer to the time when it is dark because of night. Hence it fits the requirements of an antonym  "daylight," while referring to night and darkness.

If you wish to be less poetic, you could also use **darkness of night.** As in, "He fled under the darkness of night." The opposite would be "She approached in broad daylight." If you want the poetic version, it's "He fled in the dark of night."

For other uses, like daylight as an adjective, you just again have to move the words around. "Daylight" hours becomes "the dark hours of night." Other times you need to use "in"; daylight meal becomes "meal in the dark of night." The phrases that don't work do so because they just make no sense dealing with darkness and night. Or because they don't really work with "daylight" either (such as using it as a verb).

The point, again, is that it is an antonym that fits the requirement set out by the OP. It uses both dark and night, and is fairly common.

Comment: I did fail to notice that my original edit did go through, and I've added more to make my case that this works. I don't think you can argue that it is not a better choice than "nightdark." There's no need use a neologism that sounds awkward when an existing phrase will do.