# What's a parallel for 'mitigate', for worsening a good situation?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I recently read an article claiming that employing some tactic was OK but could **mitigate** many of the good effects of the main action.

What word should the author have used, as **mitigate** means to improve or to lessen a negative, not to render a positive thing less good?

There may be no single word, but one keeps hovering around the edges of my memory...

EDIT:

Some have pointed out that this usage is correct because there is an authority for it. However, a survey of responses here seems to indicate that most people do not recognize this usage, and that view is what I'm basing this question on.

So to rephrase: what other word(s) *could* the author have used, to avoid confusion with the popular understanding of **mitigate**?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a prescriptive peeve rather than actual language usage. _Mitigate_ has been used to mean “counteract, qualify, or moderate (something neutral or positive)” ([OED definition 9](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120278)) for at least 150 years, by such prominent writers as E.M. Forster. There’s nothing wrong with how the author of your tactic used the word, even if it’s not the original sense of the word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - That is a great shout.  I did not know that mitigate could be used in that way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Good find. But I'd hardly call this 'prescriptive' since the descriptive POV (the popular and by far the top-level usage) is what I based this on. Were it somewhere north of the 9th OED entry I'd feel more chastened.

Comment: I agree that it’s less common, but I’ve heard it used this way to recognise it and not think it odd, even if I’d probably not be that likely to use it for outright positive things myself. Don’t forget that the OED’s entries are (roughly) chronological, not ordered by frequency; so the fact that it’s the ninth definition doesn’t mean the previous eight are more common (several of them are very rare or obsolete), just that they are attested earlier.

Comment: I actually think mitigate works fine here.  Per dictionary.reference.com, mitigate means "to become milder; lessen in severity".  This doesn't sound to me like it only applies to bad things.

Comment: milder from an worse, unmild condition and lessening of a severe situation both are lessening a negative.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A question based on a misconception isn't off-topic. It is answerable by addressing the faulty premise. [Example](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/205284/16310)

Comment: It also works fine as a single word request, if you ignore the point about word usage. I see that as tangential to the main question.

Comment: "Eviscerate" comes to mind, but it's perhaps a bit extreme.

Comment: Actually, if depending on how extreme the effect is, "sabotage" is a pretty good fit.  And the synonyms: vandalize, wreck, damage, destroy, cripple, impair, incapacitate, obstruct, disrupt, spoil, ruin, undermine, threaten, and subvert.  ("Undermine" seems particularly appropriate.)

Comment: "moderate" the good effects?

Comment: The Merriam-Webster dictionary gives a definition of "mitigate" that has only negative connotations: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mitigate

Comment: Since something can be described as an "unmitigated success" (implying that success, a good thing, can be mitigated), wouldn't mitigate be a neutral word.

Comment: I disagree completely that it's based on a "prescriptive" peeve. Descriptionism being the idea that words mean what we believe they mean... I've *never* heard "mitigate" used to describe protecting against positive effects, only negative ones. If I heard it used like that, I'd think it was at the very least weird and awkward.

Comment: @neminem So you've never heard of an _unmitigated success_? That's quite a common collocation where the word is used in the sense of ‘reduced the intensity of [something positive]’. It's a commonly held prescriptivist view that it is ‘wrong’ when people use _mitigate_ in the sense just quoted, and questions based on such peeves are indeed off-topic here. The way this question was worded (“since _mitigate_ means _X_, not _Y_”) made it look like it was based on such a peeve, though it seems the asker just had never that sense of the word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've heard that collocation, but I would argue that collocations don't always reflect the use of a word outside of that collocation. I would say "unmitigated success", or "unmitigated disaster", but I'm not sure I'd really use the word "unmitigated" much outside of those collocations, so it's arguable how much that reflects the use of the clearly-related, but not the same, verb "to mitigate".

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are looking for a word that means to make a good thing less good, rather than to make a bad thing worse, a possibility would be *[vitiate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vitiate)*:-

> To reduce the value or impair the quality of. [American Heritage Dictionary via The Free Dictionary]

or

> to make faulty or imperfect [Collins English Dictionary via The Free Dictionary]

Comment: Very close, and a good word in any case. Best so far.

Comment: I have entirely refrained from voting on this question. I would just like to point out that I like every word here *except* this one that I'd never heard, had to look up and had to be pronounced for me.

Comment: Indeed. It's exactly the right word, the problem is that maybe 1 in 100 people would understand it. :-) Mind you, if the context is clear enough, using it could improve that number...

Comment: I feel like 1 in 100 is probably far too kind. It's an interesting word, but I read a lot and know a fair number of words, and I've never heard that word used once.

Comment: Commonality of the word is not necessarily an issue.  If it is appropriate, use it, and the entropy will increase. :)

Answer (score 45):

What of **undermine**?

If a good thing is proposed or implemented and something else weakens it, I would think that undermine would be a good choice:

Merriam Webster has these definitions (among others):

> to subvert or weaken insidiously or secretly

or

> to weaken or ruin by degrees

Comment: Similarly, I'm a fan of **hamper** (the verb), which google defines as "to hinder or impede the movement or progress of."

Comment: Any synonym of 'reduce' will do, but this is the best one on the page for the exact sentence in the question, particularly because it has the correct connotations about undoing something good.

Comment: @RogerFilmyer: Whereas I'm a fan of **hamper**, the noun -- particularly ones from Fortnum & Mason's. ;-)

Answer (score 42):

To mitigate means to lessen the severity of a situation. You're looking for a word to make a situation worse. There are a couple of multiple antonyms at the same level of formality:

- exacerbate
- aggravate

More informally would be

- worsen

Comment: Exacerbate is used to describe making a *bad* thing worse.  The OP is asking for a term for making a *good* thing worse.  You wouldn't exacerbate cash savings, for example.

Comment: Good point, but tell that to [M-W, free dictionary, etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=antonym%20mitigate)

Comment: Can't argue with those.

Comment: Those links don't actually support this usage. The idea isn't to find an antonym for mitigate, it's to find a word with similar connotations for a positive thing as opposed to a negative thing.

Comment: @barbecue: [There are many ways to be the 'opposite'](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/185029/4972)

Comment: The only piece of this answer that is even vaguely in the spirit of the question is *worsen*. The "justification" for suggesting *exacerbate* and *aggravate* completely misses the point.

Comment: ex·ac·er·bate, transitive verb:  to make more violent, bitter, or severe <the new law only exacerbates the problem> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exacerbate) -- You can always *exacerbate the situation*. It doesn't matter if it's good or bad, exacerbating always makes it *worse*.

Comment: @mitch: The OP wasn't asking for an antonym, or an opposite. He was asking for an analogous word that could be applied in a different context.

Comment: @Mazura, no, that's not correct. Exacerbate does mean to make something already negative more negative. Nobody uses exacerbate to describe a good day turning into a bad day. In your own quotation, it says "to make MORE violent, bitter, or severe." In other words, the situation is already violent, or bitter, or severe, and is being made worse.

Answer (score 30):

**Compromise** : To reduce the quality, value, or degree of something; damage, put in danger.

E.g:

```
The affair seriously compromised the party's prospects of success
```

Comment: I like this one. Not exactly what I had in mind but it does the job.

Comment: Yes, I just had need for such a word, and this one came to mind first.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer. Also commonly in use.

Answer (score 11):

I'll go ahead and submit that the author already used *mitigate* properly. My printed copy of the *American Heritage Dictionary, Second College Edition* gives this, and only this, definition (and etymology):

> To make or become less severe or intense; moderate. [ME *mitigaten* < Lat. *mitigare* < *mitis,* soft.]

Several people have focused on the "less severe" part of the definition, which is fair. I don't think anyone will dispute that *mitigate* is most commonly used to mean "to make something bad less bad". But the definition above also says "or intense", and surely good things can be made less intense.

Regardless, I would argue that "to make *milder*" much more accurately captures *mitigate* than "to make *better*", or even "to make *less bad*". As such, I feel the author's intent was clearly, and perhaps even a bit colorfully, expressed.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the word you are looking for may be:

- negate

or possibly, in this example

- counter

Comment: You know, on seeing **compromise** and **counter** I think **offset** might be a good candidate as well.

Comment: Counter and offset seem to work. Negate feels a little too harsh to me. It implies a direct cancelling out of an action, not just a decrease in intensity of effect.

Comment: Along the same lines as *counter* is *counteract*.  That's the word I would probably use here.

Answer (score 9):

While mitigate definitely is appropriate here, I might argue that it has a connotation which suggests that it is the lessening of the effects of something bad.  Which I think is related to how the word is typically used.  Also, something of note is that Google defines mitigation as

> the action of reducing the severity, seriousness, or painfulness of
>   something.

Personally I feel it is somewhat awkward to refer to the seriousness or severity of something good.

All of that aside, I feel a more appropriate word for the sentence is diminish.

> employing some tactic was OK but could ***diminish*** many of the good
>   effects of the main action

(Another good word that is used here in other answers as part of some definitions is the word *reduce*.)

Comment: diminish is irrespective of the positive or negative nature of whatever you're diminishing... it's about amount, or degree.

Answer (score 3):

**Adulterate**: to debase something

Answer (score 3):

How about a *degradation* of the positive situation?

Answer (score 2):

A word that can be used for reducing a positive is **dissipate**.

Its second definition is squander or fritter away (money, energy, or resources).
(Google Search Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

Although the definition doesn't fit exactly, I've frequently heard the word ***degrade*** used in this context:

> "employing this tactic is OK but can **degrade** many of the benefits"

I would reserve this for colloquial usage only, though.

Answer (score 1):

> employing some tactic was OK but "could **mitigate** many of the good effects" of the main action

Rather than "mitigate" there are weaken, eliminate, dilute, lose, and negate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional verbs, not yet mentioned, that can be used.

• *pollute*, “To make something ... less suitable for some activity...” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pollute#Verb)
• *tarnish*, “To soil, sully, damage or compromise” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tarnish#Verb)
• *sully*, “to soil or stain; to dirty” and “to damage or corrupt” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sully#Verb)
• *soil*, “To stain or mar, as with infamy or disgrace; to tarnish; to sully” and “To make invalid, to ruin” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soil#Verb)
• *besmirch*, “To make dirty; to soil” and “To tarnish, especially someone's reputation; to debase” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/besmirch#Verb)
• *taint*, “To contaminate or corrupt (something)...” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taint#Verb)
• *contaminate*, “To soil or corrupt by contact; to tarnish; to pollute” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contaminate#Verb)
• *depreciate*, “(transitive) To lessen in price or estimated value; to lower the worth of...” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/depreciate#Verb) [Eg, “This sub-action will depreciate the value of the main action.”]

Answer (score -2):

"His sour expression ***minimized*** the effectiveness of his apology".